# Kafka - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id - LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: apache-kafka

I have setup Kafka cluster locally. Three broker's with properties :

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9091

broker.id=2
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9090
```

Things were working fine but I am now getting error :

> WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {TRAIL_TOPIC=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

I am also trying to write messages via Java based client & I am getting error : unable to fetch metadata in 6000ms.

Comment: It seems the topic is not existing

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, it is because the topic does not exist and the configuration of broker `auto.create.topics.enable` by default is set to `false`. I was using `bin/connect-standalone` so I didn't specify topics I would use.

I changed this config to `true` and it solved my problem.

Comment: There are many reasons for `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE`. Most common is that replication is not working, or the brokers are down... You get a different message for `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION` when a leader **is available**. Besides, you should really create your topics ahead of time when using a Source connector. Similarly, for a Sink connector, there would need to be an existing topic to read from.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for advices! It would be really nice if I could see such comment when I was solving the problem.